# Is it possible to replace condition (c) by another condition for the case of sequences with finite number of elements

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Definition**: $(u_{k})_{k≥1}$ and $(v_{k})_{k≥1}$ are two adjacent sequences with the common limit $a$, if:

(a) $(v_{k})_{k≥1}$ is decreasing

(b) $(u_{k})_{k≥1}$ is increasing

(c) $\lim \limits_{k\to \infty}(u_{k}-v_{k})=0$

As a **direct consequence** we get

$$u_{k}≤a≤v_{k}\,\ldots\ldots \tag {*}$$

for all $k≥1$.

My **question** is: Is it possible to replace condition (c) by another condition to get $(*)$. Specifically, for the case of the sequences $(u_{k})_{k≥1}$ and $(v_{k})_{k≥1}$ being finite, i.e., $k$ does tends to $∞$. Without using the notion of limit here. I have no idea to start.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with the sequences being finite.

Comment: @GitGud: sequences with finite  number of elements

Comment: Do you mean that a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is finite if, and only if, $\left\{a_n\colon n\in \mathbb N\right\}$ is finite?

Comment: @DER sequence with finite number of elements converges to 'a' means that the sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: @GitGud: I mean without using the notion of limit here.